# Python: How to properly call a method?

Tags: python-2.7, class, methods, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I have this class:

```
class Tumor(object):
    """
    Wrapper for the tumor data points.

    Attributes:
        idNum = ID number for the tumor (is unique) (int)
        malignant = label for this tumor (either 'M' for malignant 
                    or 'B' for benign) (string)
        featureNames = names of all features used in this Tumor 
                       instance (list of strings)
        featureVals = values of all features used in this Tumor
                       instance, same order as featureNames (list of floats)
    """
    def __init__(self, idNum, malignant, featureNames, featureVals):
        self.idNum = idNum
        self.label = malignant
        self.featureNames = featureNames
        self.featureVals = featureVals
    def distance(self, other):
        dist = 0.0
        for i in range(len(self.featureVals)):
            dist += abs(self.featureVals[i] - other.featureVals[i])**2
        return dist**0.5
    def getLabel(self):
        return self.label
    def getFeatures(self):
        return self.featureVals
    def getFeatureNames(self):
        return self.featureNames
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.idNum) + ', ' + str(self.label) + ', ' \
               + str(self.featureVals)
```

and I am trying to use an instance of it in another function later in my code:

```
def train_model(train_set):
    """
    Trains a logistic regression model with the given dataset

    train_set (list): list of data points of type Tumor

    Returns a model of type sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression
            fit to the training data
    """
    tumor = Tumor()
    features = tumor.getFeatures()
    labels = tumor.getLabel()
    log_reg = sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression(train_set)
    model = log_reg.fit(features, labels)

    return model
```

However, I keep getting this error when I test my code:

```
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 5 arguments (1 given)
```

I understand that I am not using the five arguments when I create the instance of     Tumor    in     train_model    , but how can I do so?

Comment: but ... you are calling functions with arguments elsewhere in your code without asking how ...? Do the same with that. `tumor = Tumor(1,2,3,4)`  [Edit: ohh, it's not clear that it's the call to the class name which triggers the __init__ method! OK, I get it.]

Comment: Well, do you have an ID number, a label, feature names, and feature values to pass it?

Comment: your question is not really clear. the init method requires some values and you are the only one that knows where to find them (since it's your script).

Answer (score 0):

Arguments to the `__init__` (or `__new__`, if you're using that) just go, predictably, where you create the instance in train_model:

```
tumor = Tumor(idNum, malignant, featureNames, featureVals)
```

Of course, you actually need values for all of these, as they are all required arguments.

You don't need to include `self`, however, as that first argument is taken care of automatically.